# Adding Facebook app permissions for development purposes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to add some additional permissions to my Facebook app, namely user_likes, user_events, and user_interests to test out the functionality of each before I go into a hackathon project. However, while doing this from "Status and Review" it seems the Facebook app requires a logo, description, and privacy policy URL to even be able to request these permissions. Futhermore, the app doesn't even exist yet, so there is no such thing as a privacy policy page yet.

How can I test out some of these additional permissions just for development purposes? I tried creating a test app but this doesn't seem to have any sort of option to add permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to do anything special while your app in development mode. Just create the app and add permissions to your login code and test. That's it.!

The permissions are added in the login code using the `scope` parameter. [Click here for more details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0).

For Example, if using-

**JS SDK-**

```
FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
}, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
```

**Manual login flow-**

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
  client_id={app-id}&
  redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&
  auth_type=rerequest&
  scope=manage_pages
```

After your app is ready, send for the review with details regarding these additional permissions, privacy policy etc.

Comment: Manual login-flow version helped me, Mr. Mittal.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to request additional permissions during the login phase, during development and while in sandbox mode, without going through any review.

During this time you're restricted to test users and others users explicitly added to the Testers section of the Roles page for your app on developers.facebook.com.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

Only when making the app visible to all members of the public do you have to go through review.